# Parse coding issue in R

Tags: r

I am trying to run this R script in one software and I received the following error:

**Error in parse(text = script) : parse error in text argument: parse error at 'Hyp.q.forward.fun' (line 5, characters 1 through 17)**

Line 5 starts from here:

```
Hyp.q.forward.fun = function(time,Hyp.qi,Hyp.b,Hyp.Di){
      Hyp.q.theo = Hyp.qi*(1+Hyp.b*Hyp.Di*time)^(-1/Hyp.b)
        return(Hyp.q.theo)
```

I am not sure why it gives an error. Could it be something wrong with line 3:

```
if(file.exists(tdir)&&file.info(dir)$isdir) suppressWarnings(try(save(list=Is(),file=paste))
```

The top 3 lines maybe not be useful to me as I already have a data table available in the software.

Can someone help on this, plz?

Thanks!

Here is the my code:

```
TimeStamp=paste(date(),Sys.timezone())
    tdir='C:/Demo'
    if(file.exists(tdir)&&file.info(dir)$isdir) suppressWarnings(try(save(list=Is(),file=paste))
    
    Hyp.q.forward.fun = function(time,Hyp.qi,Hyp.b,Hyp.Di){
      Hyp.q.theo = Hyp.qi*(1+Hyp.b*Hyp.Di*time)^(-1/Hyp.b)
        return(Hyp.q.theo)
    }
    
    residfun=function(x,x.days,y.prod){
      Hyp.qi = x[1]
      Hyp.b  = x[2]
      Hyp.Di = x[3]
      q.theo=(365.25/12)*Hyp.q.forward.fun(
        time=x.days,
        Hyp.qi=Hyp.qi,
        Hyp.b=Hyp.b,
        Hyp.Di=Hyp.Di)
      #plot(x.days,y.prod);lines(x.dauys,q.theo)
      residual=sqrt(sum((q.theo-y.prod)^2))
      return(residual)
     }
     
     min.data=3
     
     result = data.frame(
        time.days=numeric(0),
        time.months=numeric(0),
        production=numeric(0),
        theo=numeric(0)
    )
    Hyp.qi = as.numeric(NA)
    Hyp.b = as.numeric(NA)
    Hyp.Di.daily=as.numeric(NA)
    Hyp.Di.annual=as.numeric(NA)
    
    ok=length(col.Production)>0
    if(ok) ok = length(col.Date)==length(col.Production)
    
    if(ok){
        u.order=order(col.Date)
        
        col.Date=col.Date(u.order)
        col.Production=col.Production(u.order)
        
        t.days=as.numeric(difftime(col.Date,min(col.Date),units="days"))
        t.months=round(t.days*12/365.25)
        
        u0=which.max(col.Production)
        u=u0:length(col.Production)
        
        x.months=t.months[u]
        x.days=t.days[u]
        y.prod=col.Production[u]
        
        x0=c(y.prod[1]*12/365.25,1.00,0.005)
        
        optim.result=optim(
         par=x0,
         fn=residfun,
         x.days=x.days,y.prod=y.prod
        )
        
        Hyp.qi = optim.result$par[1]*(365.25/12) #monthly
        Hyp.b  = optim.result$par[2]
        Hyp.Di.daily  = optim.result$par[3]
        Hyp.Di.annual = optim.result$par[3]*365.25#annualized
        
        results=data.frame(
            time.days=x.days,
            time.months=x.months,
            production=y.prod
        )
    }
```

Comment: what is `Is()`? do you mean `file.info(tdir)$isdir` instead of `file.info(dir)$isdir`?

Comment: line 3 is missing a closing `)`

Comment: "I am trying to run this R script in one software" I suggest you first run it in R directly. That will provide more informative error messages and make it obvious that the issue is a simple syntax error (as @Waldi pointed out).

Comment: @waldi Thank you both for your replies and I was able to fix this part yesterday night. I am new to R and I am running this script because there is one example online. Could you please look at this error? 

The data function 'DCA data function' could not be executed.

Error in withCallingHandlers({
    TimeStamp = paste(date(), Sys.time : could not find function "col.Date"
    eval(script, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    eval(script, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    withCallingHandlers({

Comment: I am currently using the data table i created in my software and this script will take the production dates and oil rates from the data table to calculate the decline curve